# Is the empirical coverage rate of a confidence interval equal to the test's acceptance rate for a correct estimate (in a simulation study)?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, simulation, coverage-probability

I am conducting a simulation study to assess the performance of several confidence intervals.

My approach is to simulated (N = 10000) datasets, estimate the parameters, construct a confidence interval, and for each simulated path check whether the true parameter is in interval estimate. This results is an empirical coverage rate.

This simulation study is a replication of an existing study, and I possess over the author's code. The author has a different approach: simulate (N = 10000) datasets, estimate the parameters, calculate the p-value of the test with H_0: estimate = true parameter, the empirical coverage rate is given by the fraction of times p-value > a for a confidence interval with level 1 - a.

The results of our approaches differ. If I apply the procedure of the author in my code I get the same results as the author. Hence my estimation procedures etc. work well. This raises my question on whether the procedure of the author is correct or not?

Thanks for your time.